# Dynamic data model creation using Class::MOP::Class not working

Tags: perl, dynamic, instance, creation

I have Schema definitions in JSON files which I would like to read and generate Classes dynamically using Class::MOP::Class. For instance there are JSON files A.json, B.json, C.json which get translated to Classes A, B, C.

Now I would like to instantiate objects of A, B, C from some other data source.

```
sub generate_classes_from_schema {
    my $self = shift;
    foreach my $cname('A', 'B', 'C') {
        my $class_def = Class::MOP::Class->create($cname); 

        foreach my $att_name(get_attrib_list($cname)) {
            $class_def->add_attribute($att_name);
        }
        $self->{class_defs}->{$cname} = $class_def;
     }
 }
...
...
sub generate_object_map {
    my $self = shift;
    my $query_key = shift;
    my $obj_map = {};

    foreach my $cname('A', 'B', 'C') {
        my $row = get_rowfor_entity($cname, $query_key);
        my $entity_object = $self->{class_defs}->{$cname}->new_object(%{$row});         
        push(@{$obj_map->{$cname}, $entity_object);
    }
    return $obj_map;
}
```

When I dump the obj_map it just has a hash of key-value pairs per attribute...

```
        'A' =>
                 bless( {
                              'att_name' => 'my-att1',
                              'att1' => '4',
                              'att2' => 'false',
                              'att2' => 'true',
                            }, 'A' )
```

I was hoping the object should have auto-generated accessor methods for the attributes at the minimum. Also, when trying to add methods to class_def [$class_def->add_method(...) ] those methods also do not reflect in the Object instances from obj_map.

Could someone please explain where Iam going wrong or what should be the right approach?

Comment: `add_attribute` should take a `Class::MOP::Attribute` object where the accessors are defined, not just an attribute name.

Comment: Thanks Stevenl - Iam aware of the Class::MOP::Attribute object but was hesitant to wrap the attributes with it due to possible overhead

Comment: note that if you pass parameters to add_attribute, it will pass those parameters on to construct an attribute object anyway.

Comment: So what confuses me is the dump of object for 'A' just lists the attributes (att1, att2, att3) as key-value pairs and not as blessed object refs of Class::MOP::Attribute

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create accessor for attribute then you must define accessor's name. More about attribute & method creation & introspection see in [`Class::MOP::Class`](http://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aMOP%3a%3aClass) documentation.

```
my $class = Class::MOP::Class->create('Foo');

# Attribute & method creation.
$class->add_attribute(bar => (accessor => 'bar'));
$class->add_method(buz => sub { return 'buz'; });

# Attribute & method introspection.
$class->get_all_attributes();
$class->get_all_methods();
```

Comment: Thanks dionys this should help!

Comment: Any options whats the best way to introduce methods (as i indicated earlier i tried with add_method()). Also, how about introducing  Class methods, say get_attribute_list() which the users can access via the object_references to loop over ALL attributes specific to the object?

Comment: Thanks. My Intention was to have the Users only deal with the object references which they get hold of from generate_object_map(). So for example: $obj_map->{$cname}->get_att1(); $obj_map->{$cname}->get_attribute_list(); etc... As far as possible avoid having to deal with $class directly. The above calls result in error saying get_attribute_list() is undefined when called through $obj_ref. Is there a way I can make this happen?